# SmtpClient: The maximum number of concurrent connections has exceeded a limit

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have a following method which I call for every MailMessage:

```
public static string SendEmail(MailMessage email)
        {
            string rez = "";

            try
            {
                var smtpserver = "10.xxx.xx.xx"; 

                using (SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                   mailclient.Host = smtpserver;

                   mailclient.Send(email);

                }

                rez = "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rez = "NOT OK: " + ex.Message;
            }

            return rez;
        }
```

I send 32 email-s at once, and for two of them I got following error from mailclient.Send(): 
**NOT OK: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 The maximum number of concurrent connections has exceeded a limit, closing transmission channel**

I was wondering if this is because I created a new SmtpClient instance for every mail?

Will the following change fix the problem since there is only one instance of SmtpClient. UnfortunatellyI cannot test it, I can only try it in production.

```
public static SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient("10.xxx.xx.xx");

 public static string SendEmail(MailMessage email)
            {
                string rez = "";

                try
                {

                       mailclient.Send(email);


                    rez = "OK";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    rez = "NOT OK: " + ex.Message;
                }

                return rez;
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: *I cannot test it, I can only try it in production.* You're doomed then. Sorry.

Comment: Try to introduce slight _delay_ between every call, say 100ms (just an example) and see if it changes something.

Comment: Normally does the `Send()`-Method block until the message is send (or failed to send), so there should be no problem sending 32 messages consecutively. Do you use Threads to execute your `SendEmail()` method?

Comment: Could this error be coming from the receiving server?

Comment: Just create a queue of emails and send out an email from the queue on a timer.

Answer (score 5):

You can reuse the instance of the SmtpClient to send emails and it is good practice (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but i think it will not solve your problem.

From MSDN

> The connection established by the current instance of the SmtpClient
>   class to the SMTP server may be re-used if an application wishes to
>   send multiple messages to the same SMTP server. This is particularly
>   useful when authentication or encryption are used establish a
>   connection to the SMTP server. The process of authenticating and
>   establishing a TLS session can be expensive operations. A requirement
>   to re-establish a connection for each message when sending a large
>   quantity of email to the same SMTP server could have a significant
>   impact on performance. There are a number of high-volume email
>   applications that send email status updates, newsletter distributions,
>   or email alerts. Also many email client applications support an
>   off-line mode where users can compose many email messages that are
>   sent later when a connection to the SMTP server is established. It is
>   typical for an email client to send all SMTP messages to a specific
>   SMTP server (provided by the Internet service provider) that then
>   forwards this email to other SMTP servers.
>
> The SmtpClient class implementation pools SMTP connections so that it
>   can avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection for every
>   message to the same server. An application may re-use the same
>   SmtpClient object to send many different emails to the same SMTP
>   server and to many different SMTP servers. As a result, there is no
>   way to determine when an application is finished using the SmtpClient
>   object and it should be cleaned up.
>
> When an SMTP session is finished and the client wishes to terminate
>   the connection, it must send a QUIT message to the server to indicate
>   that it has no more messages to send. This allows the server to free
>   up resources associated with the connection from the client and
>   process the messages which were sent by the client.
>
> The SmtpClient class has no Finalize method, so an application must
>   call Dispose to explicitly free up resources. The Dispose method
>   iterates through all established connections to the SMTP server
>   specified in the Host property and sends a QUIT message followed by
>   gracefully ending the TCP connection. The Dispose method also releases
>   the unmanaged resources used by the Socket and optionally disposes of
>   the managed resources. Call Dispose when you are finished using the
>   SmtpClient. The Dispose method leaves the SmtpClient in an unusable
>   state. After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the
>   SmtpClient so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the
>   SmtpClient was occupying.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to limit the *SMTPClient* to a certain number of connections, and I came upon this question trying to track that down.  I found a way to send multiple emails at the same time from different threads and have them stack up and run through a shared *SMTPClient* which uses one connection, releasing the next message to send using an *AutoResetEvent*.

See my answer on [Stack Overflow here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389709/why-can-smtpclient-sendasync-only-be-called-once/50820005#50820005) in a related question.